A small free dataset for 3D reconstruction from 2D images
I am trying to start coding on 3D image reconstruction from 2D images (so to map images to a 3D point cloud). Can any one please introduce a small free dataset to start with? I know BlendedMVS. But its 27 GB for its row resolution images. Does any one know a smaller dataset, preferably similar to BlendedMVS?
